# DNS resolution fails on Mac OS X for single host

Tags: macos, mac, dns

I have rather peculiar problem. I run a small local network with a dedicated Bind9 DNS server. All hosts are in an invented .lan TLD. I use soemthing like service.mydomainname.lan for addressing several services, e.g. mail, fileservice, etc. Everything works as expected with one single exception, which is rather odd. When I try to access home.mydomainname.lan, every web browser on Mac OS X tells me that it cannot resolve the host name. Other host names like mail.mydomainname.lan work perfectly. The strangest thing is that the system happily resolves the name when I use the "host" tool in a terminal. I tried to flush the cache with dscacheutil, no change. This behaviour started very recently with no particular reason. I did not change the DNS configuration, nor did I change anything on DHCP, the router or the Mac OS X machine.

Does anyone have an idea what is happening here and how I can fix it? This is really annoying, because it happens to be one of my most important services.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [here on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26616/dns-not-resolving-on-mac-os). After trying that launchtcl magic, DNS worked again.